# Склонение слова "патч", ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда следует ставить ударение, используя слово "патч" в различных падежах (кроме именительного, разумеется) - на первый слог или какой-либо другой?

Пример: родительный  пАтча или патчА?

Родительный (кого, чего?)   патча   патчей
Дательный   (кому, чему?)   патчу   патчам
Винительный (кого, что?)    патч    патчи
Творительный    (кем, чем?) патчем  патчами
Предложный  (о ком, о чём?) патче   патчах

С уважением, Владимир.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всех формах падежей ударение падает на первый слог.

Comment: Почему?...........

Answer (score 2):

Матч - мАтча, патч - пАтча.

Практически нет сомнений в том, что это существительное будет отнесено к классу А с постоянным ударением на основе.

Почему? Да просто его фонетика такова, что при смещении ударения на окончание оно станет неузнаваемым даже в своем ограниченном кругу пользователей.

Comment: Вот с последним как раз не согласен. Именно "свой круг" и склонен смещать ударения. Во-первых, сам слышал патчА (мне-то уж слух никак не режет), во-вторых, сравните все эти "кремА", "тортА", "ветра", "шоферА" (!! - дважды неправильно, потому как возможно только от шОфер) и даже  "доменА" (от дОмен - вместо нормативного домЕн) и прочее. Тут другое. Нет подходящей парадигмы именно для односложных слов. Вообще таких слов со смещением ударения в падежах единственного числа почти нет.

Comment: Крема и торта - это, конечно, ненормативно, но понятно, а вот в слово  "патчА" сочетание ТЧ будет, скорее всего,  произносится как удлиненный звук Ч, в этом и заключается трудность узнавания. Попробуйте произнести "матчА", ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет.

Comment: А, ну фонетическое объяснение я еще могу принять в принципе принять. В принципе, потому, как здесь все-таки делается попытка объяснить. Но в данном случае очень сомневаюсь... МатчА - да не слышал. А патчА, как сказал, слышал. И ухо не режет.

Comment: (+), нет, никакого "удвоенного Ч" там нету. Вполне явственное "ТЧ". Разница в том, что "удвоенное Ч" дает  (в укнаинском, например) [Т'Ш'-Ш'] (долгое Ш'), а ТЧ - [Т-Т'Ш'] ("долгое" Т, т.е. с паузой на затворе). Причем первое Т в этом случае даже не обязательно мягкое. Я так это слышу. Так вот в патча (с любым ударением) - именно долгое Т, так произносят "профи" в отличие от матча, которое скорее с долгим Ш'.

Comment: По поводу фонетики спорить сложно, а как насчет грамматики? Вот, например, фраза: " Я с патчем работаю мало", окончание в Т.п. безударное. Это какой же акцентный тип мы тогда получаем: патчА - пАтчем? Или вы говорите "патчОм"?

Comment: Я  - не говорю так. )) А те, кто говорит, говорят, конечно, патчОм. Смещать - так смещать.

Comment: Несолидно как-то звучит, на сленг очень похоже. Если и применять такую форму, то  лучше как разговорный вариант в кругу хороших знакомых.

Comment: Так мы же про сленг и говорим, нет? Я раза три сказал, что речь идет о **профжаргоне**.

Comment: Компьютерный профжаргон часто называют просто компьютерным языком. А "патчА, патчОм"  - это такой нарочитый (показной, подчеркнутый) сленг.

Comment: Это Вы мне рассказываете? Я 35 лет программистом проработал. ))) С институтом - все 40.  Вы откатите взор на начало разговора, я все так и сказал.

Answer (score 2):

Всем большое спасибо за отзывы :)

Особая благодарность Сержу за отправку к Викисловарю - в будущем буду предварительно просматривать его при возникших сомнениях :)

Пойду тыкать в словарик лицевой поверхностью девушку, ставящую ударение на второй слог при склонении по падежам искомого пАтчика :)

С уважением, Владимир.

Answer (score 0):

Слово пока не фиксируется нормативными орфоэпическими словарями, поэтому утверждать ничего наверняка нельзя.
Ну по аналогии можно предположить сохранение ударения на первом слоге. Смещение ударения обычно происходит у слов исконно русских или давно освоенных языком (причина этого - в особенностях старорусской фонетики, сохранившей некоторые рефлексы разделения гласных на долгие и краткие). Новые заимствования обычно следуют общим правилам. И поскольку правило сохранения ударения в односложных словах такого типа более распространено, можно ожидать, что и слово "патч" сохранит ударение при изменении по падежам.

Comment: behemothus, см. Викисловарь.

Comment: А что там смотреть? Его уже признали нормативным?